# play protect issue with flavors

Tags: android, android-productflavors, android-flavors, google-play-protect

when I try to install my release apk google play protect will error.
I have five flavors from this application and one of them is on the google play store.
when I install the app which is on the play store, directly it will install without error.
but when I try to install other flavors that aren't in the play store, google play protect will warn me about that apk.
I don't know how to fix this issue.

Comment: same problem here,if you fixed can you please share with us how

Comment: @pic we published our app on the google play store and we submitted forms for each flavor.
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/contact/protectappeals
after some downloads from the google play, the problem have been solved automaticlly.